# Connecting Kinect to Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, kinect

So I'm trying to hook up a Kinect to an Android tablet using any means necessary. I would preferably like to avoid a windows machine or arduino board in the middle.

The method I've already tried is to have a C# program (the kinect sdk uses C#) communicate with the android device. I tried to figure out how to send a message through usb, and decided to do port forwarding. This worked, but was slower than I would like it to be.

I guess the question is can I connect it to Android as a usb device or accessory and communicate via JNI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: OpenNI on Android]

In theory you should be able to use the OpenNI for ARM. I've seen [Hirotaka's demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRc1oXB8kPE) of OpenNI running on Linaro Android but using an Asus Xtion Pro sensor and a Panda board.
Hirotaka also [posted notes](http://www.hirotakaster.com/archives/2012/03/openni-for-android-apk-and-shared-binaries.php) on his setup.

Doing a [quick youtube search](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kinect%20on%20android&page=&utm_source=opensearch) reveals examples with Kinect and Android tablets.

---

Side note: I don't I understand why you're trying to use C#: you'll be writing Android applications in Java and OpenNI has a Java wrapper.

Comment: Cool, Thanks! To answer your question, I was connecting the kinect to my laptop which was running a c# program that communicates with an android device using adb's port forwarding. Overly complicated, but I didn't know how else to proceed.